# python3: convert list of lists to dictionary of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am facing a problem with one of my python script when trying to convert a list of lists to a dictionary of lists.

Here is what I have: a list of lists of ID numbers.

```
a = [ [0,1,2,5] , [4,5] , [0,4] , [2,5] ]
```

And I need to convert it in a dictionary of lists, in which keys correspond to each ID number and values are the list of ID numbers found with the key in the previous list of lists.
That would be:

```
b = { 0 : [1,2,5,4] , 1 : [0,2,5] , 2 : [0,1,5] , 4 : [0,5] , 5 : [0,1,2,4] }
```

My original list of lists (a) is composed of 70,000 lists, and each of them consists on 2 to 5000 ID numbers (about 50,000 different ID numbers in total).

I came up with a very nasty code (tons of for loops) that requires about 3mn to perform this conversion.
Would anyone have a suggestion to do it in a efficient (i.e. fast) way ? There might be a python library I don't know about.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you get your result. Wouldn't `b[0]` be `[0, 2]`, because 0 is found in the first and third list? Or am I misunderstanding your specification?

Comment: your example isn't clear, can you describe it step-by-step?

Comment: @L3viathan he doesn't collect indices, he collects friends from the same list. `0` has friends `1, 2, 5` in the first list, and `4` in the third one.

Comment: Amadan is correct, my apologies if my explanations are not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way faster than this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
b = defaultdict(set)
for subl in a:
    for el in subl:
        for other_el in subl:
            if other_el != el:
                b[el].add(other_el)
```

You end up with sets as dict values, but if you need lists it is easy enough to do:

```
b = { k: list(v) for k, v in b.items() }
```

Comment: that was the solution I ended up with (although this is far more elegant than what I wrote) ... correct results, and 'decently' fast

Comment: As I said, I can't think of how it might be written faster, short of changing the language to something faster and not-Python. The three loops are the absolute minimum that you can do this with.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a way of doing this in one "line":

```
b = {
    key: list({
        val
        for relevant in (candidate for candidate in a if key in candidate)
            for val in relevant
        if key != val
    }) for sublist in a for key in sublist
}
```

But a solution with nested loops might actually be faster.

The weird `list({...})` construction is there to ensure the elements are listed only once per list (by collecting them in a set first).

Comment: "But a solution with nested loops might actually be faster."